# Android View Pager: onCreateView getting called for both fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement swipe views with 2 tabs. For that, I am using view pager with 2 fragments. Now, the problem is that as soon as the main activity is opened (that contains those two tabs), onCreateView function is called for both the fragments. Please help me as how can I avoid calling of onCreateView of second fragment when one is in use.

Thanks,
Arpit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ViewPager` retains the fragment to the left and to the right of the current view by default. This is to reduce a choppy user experience - that way you can begin swiping left or right and immediately see what is there without delay.

It is possible to disable (or increase the number of fragments to be retained) with [setOffscreenPageLimit(0)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)), but seriously consider if this is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks @ekchang for your reply. Do you know if there is a callback when second tab is selected (fragment to the right is swiped) ?

Comment: You can extend [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and override all sorts of callbacks; it sounds like `onPageSelected(int position)` is the one you are looking for.